# Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial150.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

this controller works very good at my local

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult checkout(CheckOut a,int[] degerler)
    {
        ETLEntities db = new ETLEntities();
        
       Basket basket = new Basket();
        var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(User.Identity.GetUserName());
 
        basket.Customer_Id = user.Id;
        basket.total_value = GetCart().Total();
        basket.description = a.Description;
        basket.Height = a.Height; 
        db.Basket.Add(basket);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Basket_Product  s = new Basket_Product();
       var BAM= GetCart().CartLines.ToList();
        foreach (var item in BAM)
        {
            s.Basket_Id=basket.Id;
            s.Product_Id = item.Product.Id;
            s.Quantity_Number=item.Quantity;
            db.Basket_Product.Add(s);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        Orders order = new Orders();
        foreach (var item in degerler)
        {
          
            order.Customer_Id = user.Id;
            order.Address_Id = item;
            order.Order_Situation_id = 1;
            order.Basket_Id = basket.Id;
            order.Storage_Employee_Id = db.Storage_Employee.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Employee_Statement_Id == 3).Id;
            order.Transport_Employee_Id = db.Transport_Employee.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Employee_Statement_Id == 3).Id;
            order.Created_At= DateTime.Now;
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
      

        return RedirectToAction("sipalindi","NetButik");

    }
```

But when ı publish my project ı get Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial150.dll':
error ı am trying the solve this problem about 3 days but ı cant find the solution of problem  ı will be appriciate if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. I had a column in my database table, when I deleted this column, the problem disappeared, but if I need this location, I still don't know what to do, if anyone knows, I would be very happy if they could share it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).